# How to remove default font of the HTML?

Tags: html, css

I decided to use ubuntu font-family for my angular project.I overrided it succesfully.But when I refresh the page,page starts with default font then in miliseconds turning into my ubuntu font.I just want it start with ubuntu not something else.How can I remove that default font of the html.

my styles.css below

```
* {
   font-family: 'Ubuntu';       
 }
```

how I defined my fonts.css under assets on the angular.json

```
   "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/css/fonts.css",
            ],
```

what's under my fonts.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-display: swap;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('../fonts/ubuntu-v12-latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-300.eot');
    /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local('Ubuntu Light'), local('Ubuntu-Light'), url('../fonts/ubuntu-v12-latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('../fonts/ubuntu-v12-latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-300.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
    url('../fonts/ubuntu-v12-latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-300.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('../fonts/ubuntu-v12-latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-300.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('../fonts/ubuntu-v12-latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-300.svg#Ubuntu') format('svg');
    /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Screenshot from my console to show you how its overwritten
[image]

Comment: Because you are loading the font and that takes time, this is not easy to prevent from happening. What if the font doesn't get loaded at all? Should it not use the system font in that circumstance and just hide your text? Here's an article about this 'problem' here: https://www.malthemilthers.com/font-loading-strategy-acceptable-flash-of-invisible-text/ - two choices, and neither are great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a custom font from a file (using `@font-face`), the browser has to download that font before it can use it (unless the font already exists on the user's machine). While still in the process of fetching the custom font, most browsers will render all affected text in a fallback font. This brief moment is what is known as *"Flash of Unstyled Text"* (FOUT).

While there is no guaranteed way to prevent the FOUT, there are ways to improve the situation. I'll outline two.

### Pre-loading fonts

Add this to the `<head>` of your page, before the inclusion of your CSS:

```
<link rel="preload" href="../fonts/ubuntu-v12-latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-300.eot" as="font">
```

This let's the browser know that you would like to preload the font with high priority, so that it's available as soon as possible. More details can be found in [this Google article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/webfont-optimization#preload_your_webfont_resources).

### Using `font-display`

Change your `font-display` rule to `block`:

```
font-display: block;
```

This tells the browser to display no text until the custom font has been loaded. More details can be found in [the same article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/webfont-optimization#customize_the_text_rendering_delay)

Answer (score 1):

when someone uses the custom fonts it is normal behavior of the browsers/OS to display the normal font first and once the loading or downloading of the custom font is done then show that particular font on the page. This is known as FOUT.

Read about this [here](https://medium.com/@ngubanethabo.ambrose/prevent-text-font-flickering-caused-by-using-a-custom-font-family-983c4b8d548d)
[Web Font flickering on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922285/web-font-flickering-on-load)

UPDATED: You are already using font-face. Hence, removing the suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you haven't took a look on my question how I defined fonts there.Already under the @font-face{} . Thanks for your interest though

Comment: I missed that. Sorry, for duplication...however, FOUT will remain...I faced this issue a lot. If you will be able to optimize at your machine..then folks with a slow connection will face it.

Answer (score 0):

Please put fonts.css code in a reboot.scss file or remove font-family: sans-serif; in reboot.scss file.
It's loading issue your reboot.scss file load first after your fonts.css load that is the main problem.

Comment: Where is that reboot.scss file in the project?I couldn't find

Comment: it's imported in bootstrap like this @import "reboot".

Comment: I found the file I removed those lines about font-family but still HTML renders them before my font

Comment: Than load fonts.css file first of all CSS file.

Comment: I mean call your fonts.css file first before all other CSS files.
when you view page source your fonts.css file load first in the head.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201193/discussion-between-keyur-gajjar-and-timucin-cicek).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the font-face that you are using. Until your desired font loads, the browser tries to display the default set font-face. You can try to install that font in your system and change your default browser font from settings.

Comment: Yeah I can do that but when another user opens my page,then it won't be the same on his browser.I want to change permanently for all users

Comment: In that case, your target audience should have the respective font set in the browser, otherwise, that switching of fonts(milliseconds break) is inevitable.

Comment: yeah but why using bootstrap fonts don't make the page with its font after refreshed the page

Comment: As all other people say,in index.html bootstrap.min.css should be imported before than my font-styles.css .But in Angular its not possible because I imported bootstrap folder by npm